# What happens after accepting client in java server socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have server socket code, inside thread I do this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {

                Socket socket = my_serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                out.println("hi");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket
                        .getInputStream()));
                String msg = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("message is: " + msg);

                in.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Here the important places are code where I print "hi". What interests me how does accept works. Does my server send "hi" to client and the closes socket because of socket.close() line or does connection will persist in some other thread. I hope It is clear, quite hard to explain my problme.

What I need is to open connection and then inside server code (her in while loop or somewhere else) read data from queue (that is static public) and send data to the client while available. when data is not available wait, as long as data is in queue send it. This is producer consumer problem and try as folows:

```
protected static BlockingQueue<String> q;
q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
```

I declare BlockedQueue first. Then instead of printing "hi" I want some while loop or whatever. Can I do this way:

```
if ( !q.isEmpty() ){
    try {
        String temp = q.take();
        out.println(temp);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        Log.d("yerchik", "couldn't take from queue: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I suppose blocked queue handles race conditions itself.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of [`Socket#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close--) before asking the question?

Comment: accept() just creates socket. Why are you closing socket? once you close the socket, nothing will be sent over the socket. Any reasons for closing input stream and socket?  Other part -> do you want to keep if condition or while condition for q.isEmpty()?

Comment: @ravindra, yep I want my server send messages to the client during the whole connection, and I can have only one client. I am concerned is it ok to just write another while inside while where i will read strings from queue and send them to the client.

Comment: Once you call accept() method on server socket and create a client Socket, create a new thread with Socket variable. Handle all IO operations in that new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't have multiple clients getting messages, but you would need to just ignore or reject additional clients after the accept(). Each accept will create a new socket connection that I suppose you could close. Just don't close the first one.

As far as your public static queue, I always prefer to have a socket worker of some type that is Runnable and takes in its constructor the socket returned from accept().

In addition, you would create a queue in this socket worker with a public method such as queueMessage(Message message) that any other thread could add to that object's message queue. The run() method would constantly loop and consume this message queue (using synchronized access) as messages come in and pass them along via the connected socket. You could loop while the socket is connected.

Again, there is no issue with multiple connections - each worker thread would have its own message queue.